# Why does this code work for different types?

Tags: c#, generics

I am working on some class room examples. This code works but I do not see why it works. I know that there is a generic type and that class implements Item but Item is just another class. Why would this code allow a int and double into the same list.

I am sure that it has to do with the Generic but why I am not really certain.

**Question: Why does this code allow two different types into the same list?**

Class definitions:

```
public class Item<T> : Item
{
}

public class Item
{
}
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Item>();

    list.Add(new Item<int>());
    list.Add(new Item<double>());
}
```

Comment: Hint: `T` is a *Type Parameter*.  Think about what those two words mean.

Comment: Way too much code. Try to keep question code short and to the point.

Comment: Item<T>, Item<int> and Item<double> are all Item by inheritance. Since you're storing Item in the collection they all can be stored.

Comment: I've stripped your code back to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusing thing in your example is that both the base and derived classes have the label "Item".  However, with a few name changes, your code is equivalent to :

```
public class Pet {}
public class Dog : Pet {}
public class Cat : Pet {}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Pet>(); //  base type items

    list.Add(new Dog());
    list.Add(new Cat());
}
```

Even though two different types are being stored in the list, they are derived from the same base class. The key to understanding the code is that the `List<>` is a container for the base type, in this case "Pet" - and in your example the base type is "Item".

Answer (score 7):

Your confusion here is stemming from the fact that you have *two* generic types, not one. The first is the generic list, which you already understand. The second is the generic `Item` class:

```
public class Item<T> : Item
```

The definition of this class states that `Item<T>` always inherits `Item`, regardless of what type `T` is. This means, that when you create a `List<Item>`...

```
var list = new List<Item>();
```

... you can add *any* `Item<T>` to it, as any `Item<T>` is an `Item`.

Answer (score 4):

> Why would this code allow a int and double into the same list.

It works because you store `Item`, not `Item<T>`.

This equivalent code makes it easier to see:

```
//list.Add(new Item<int>());
Item item1 = new Item<int>();   // implicit conversion from Item<int> to Item
list.Add(item1);

//list.Add(new Item<double>());
Item item2 = new Item<double>();
list.Add(item2);
```

Comment: It is much easier way to see the way you did it here. Sometimes when you start adding in inheritance it does make it more confusing. I still find it strange that you can have one class inherit from the other and then the child class can be implemented but in reality of objects they objects are of the same base class type so that makes them so they can be pushed on to a collection of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

It works because `Item<T>` *is* an `Item`, so an `Item<double>` can be put in a `List<Item>`, as can an `Item<int>`

Part of the confusion may stem from the fact that you're using a similar type name (`Item` and `Item<T>`) for different classes. Although in your case one inherits from the other, there's no built-in connection between a class and a generic version of that class.